# angular ng-pattern currency regular expression

Tags: angularjs, regex, ng-pattern

I'm trying to write a regular expression for ng-pattern that will pass on the following cases:

```
.1 - Pass
.01 - Pass
0.01 - Pass
1 - Pass
1.0 - Pass
1.00 - Pass
$1.00 - Pass
$1000 - Pass
$1,000 - Pass
$1,000,000.00 Pass

11,11 - Fail
11.111 - Fail
```

This regular expression will pass and fail the appropriate cases on https://regex101.com/

```
(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$
```

However when I try this:

```
data-ng-pattern="/^(?=.)^\$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/"
```

I get the following error message:

```
 SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^(?=.)^$?(([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*)|[0-9]+)?(\.[0-9]{1,2})?$/: Nothing to repeat
```

What do I need to adjust to make this work in angular?

Comment: The second `^` has nothing to do in the middle of the regex.

Comment: Which Angular version?

Comment: Try [`data-ng-pattern="/^(?=.)[$]?([1-9][0-9]{0,2}(,[0-9]{3})*|[0-9]+)?([.][0-9]{1,2})?$/"`](https://regex101.com/r/QEGP66/1) (place `$` and `.` inside `[...]`).

Comment: (There are garbage chars in the pattern in the comment above, please do not copy/paste it from the SO comment.)

Comment: I also think you just may remove `(?=.)` and use a `ng-required="true"` attribute.